Flutter what is the best way to design a form with a button on bottom?
Edit 2:
I have created a new post where I explain better what I want to achieve
Flutter Best way to create form with a button on the bottom?
I have been searching for so long to find a good solution to my problem. I want to have this layout:
 
So far I have managed to do this:
class FormPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const FormPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<FormPage> createState() => _FormPageState();
}

class _FormPageState extends State<FormPage> {
  bool hasManyData = false;

  // List of many data
  final List<String> dataLong = List.generate(20, (index) => "Data $index");

  // List of few data
  final List<String> dataShort = List.generate(2, (index) => "Data $index");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  hasManyData = !hasManyData;
                });
              },
              child: const Text("change Data Size"),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    for (final data in hasManyData ? dataLong : dataShort)
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text(data),
                      ),
                    const TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Name",
                      ),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: const Text("Submit"),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



Which is almost the same but the submit button is not on the bottom when there are few data (you can change data size using the button).
Every way that I have tried so many things with Slivers and without always there was something breaking, I want to keep the keyboard functionality as is without overflowing or the Submit button moving up with the keyboard.
EDIT 1:
I have managed to do that:

class FormPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const FormPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<FormPage> createState() => _FormPageState();
}

class _FormPageState extends State<FormPage> {
  bool hasManyData = false;

  // List of many data
  final List<String> dataLong = List.generate(20, (index) => "Data $index");

  // List of few data
  final List<String> dataShort = List.generate(2, (index) => "Data $index");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  hasManyData = !hasManyData;
                });
              },
              child: const Text("change Data Size"),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: CustomScrollView(
                slivers: [
                  SliverFillRemaining(
                    hasScrollBody: false,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        for (final data in hasManyData ? dataLong : dataShort)
                          ListTile(
                            title: Text(data),
                          ),
                        const TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "Name",
                          ),
                        ),
                        const Spacer(),
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: const Text("Submit"),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

But now the submit button gets pushed up when the keyboard opens, and hiding the button when the keyboard opens is an option... but a very bad one imo because it takes a second for it to reapear.

Since the size of the list view items is not fixed, what you have done is correct.

@DroidFlutter But when there are not enough data to fill the screen, I want the button to be on the bottom of the screen.

I have added code with my logic. Hope it helps.

First thing take out ElevatedButton from Expanded widget:
Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: const Text("change Data Size"),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: const Text("Submit"),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)


Another way to do this, use Align widget:
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  child: ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: const Text("Submit"),
  ),
)


Sorry if I didn't make it clear on the question. when there are a lot of data and the user has to scroll to see them, I want the button to be visible right under the last data. On the code you provided the button is always visible

Try below code
late final GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();
var renderBox = null;

if (_key.currentContext?.findRenderObject() != null) {
  renderBox = _key.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
}
final height = renderBox?.size.height;

Column(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              hasManyData = !hasManyData;
            });
          },
          child: const Text("change Data Size"),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              key: _key,
              children: [
                for (final data in hasManyData ? dataLong : dataShort)
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text(data),
                  ),
                const TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Name",
                  ),
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(height: height > MediaQuery.of(context).size.height ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/1.6 : 0),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: const Text("Submit"),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );


what is the height variable? it is not initialized

I have edited my code with height variable, please check.
